# Cordova Project add Android Native Module

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a Cordova App and added a Native module to the Android project.

I have added dependencies for the module to the project, and everything works fine if I use android studio build.

However, when I execute command 'cordova build android', the file settings.gradle is auto-generated to a default setting which looks like:

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"
```

As a result, build always fails due to unable to locate module 'mymodule' even if I defined him in settings.gradle.

I tried to find the script that generate the settings.graddle file but without success, maybe I can disable the auto generate method, and use my own setting.graddle.

Could use some help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this. I keeped using Android Studio build instead of Cordova, just copy the www folder from your project and put it in folder assets of your android project, to update your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue and i found a way to adding native modules in **Cordova** project. You can use this in feature.

Step 1:
You need build and import the project in Android Studio. For that please follow [this.](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/)

step 2:

Add a new module to the project. For that please follow [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

step 3:

Find the `GradleBuilder.js` file in path `platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders`. In that file, find the function which is writing `settings.gradle` and add your module like this `'include ":YourModuleName"'`.

for older **Cordova** version the `settings.gradle` writting function is placed in `build.js` path is `platforms/android/cordova/lib`

Now you can build your **Cordova** project as usual via terminal.