# How to add native module to Cordova Android project?

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, android-module, cordova-android

I want to add a native (integration test) module to a Cordova Android project.

For fully native projects, you just add a new module, commit and be done with it. But for Cordova I of course don't really want to mess with the generated Android project as some of these changes might be lost on build etc.

I got a Poof of Concept of the module working manually by having the module folder outside of the Cordova Android folder and adding this to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':module-androidTest'
project(':module-androidTest').projectDir = new File("../module-tests")
```

But of course line 1 of that file already says

```
// GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
```

Is there any other way to add additional modules to a Cordova Android project?

---

Some approaches I researched or thought about:

- Can I somehow do this with `build-extras.gradle`? (I don't think so as `settings.gradle` is several steps before build-extras and `build.gradle`, right?)
- Older StackOverflow questions suggest manually editing a `GradleBuilder.js` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35504783/252627 But of course this would get lost each time I completely generate a new Cordova project. Not a good idea, correct?
- Can I maybe work around this somehow via a Cordova plugin? I know these can load frameworks etc - maybe also a module somehow?

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be done using a custom plugin which can extend the base gradle config using a framework tag like this: `<framework src="relative/path/to/your/gradlefile/*.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @David, but `gradleReference` "only" allows you to add additional stuff to your `build.gradle` file between the `// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START // PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END` lines of the generated `build.gradle` (which is awesome, but doesn't help me, correct?)

Comment: Well I don't know if it helps you in your specifiy use-case which is why I added it as a comment but this is how you usually extend the cordova android project.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, so I can potentially accept it if this turns out to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be done using a custom plugin which can extend the base gradle config using a framework tag like this:

```
<framework src="relative/path/to/your/gradlefile/*.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

This is how a cordova-android project is usually extended.